# 型宣言と付属型の仕組み

Tags: swift

CollectionTypeプロトコルのリファレンスを見てみると、

次のように、宣言されています。
subscript(*: Self.Index) -> Self.Base.Generator.Element

subscript(*: Self.Index) -> Self.Generator.Element

Selfは、CollectionTypeプロトコルが具体的に使用される型となる理解しています。

ただ次の型の意味が理解できません。
Self.Base.Generator.Element
Self.Generator.Element

の違い・意味分かりません。特に「Base」がわかりません。

Comment: Baseの方ですが、whereでCollectionTypeが_CollectionWrapperTypeに準拠しているときに使われるようになっているようです。_CollectionWrapperTypeの定義を見てみると「type alias Base : CollectionType」となっているので、「Self.Base.Generator.Element」と「Self.Generator.Element」は同じになるのではないでしょうか。（間違っているかもしれないです）
これらの定義ですが、リファレンスでは無く、「Array<Int>」と書いて、コマンドクリックで「Array」の定義にジャンプして、以後、その定義周辺を検索して、各定義を確認しました。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`subscript(_: Self.Index) -> Self.Base.Generator.Element`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_CollectionType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intfsub/CollectionType/s:seRq_Ss14CollectionTypeq_Ss22_CollectionWrapperTypezqq_Ss9Indexable5Indexqqq_S0_4BaseS1_5Indexzqqq_S1_5IndexSs16ForwardIndexType8Distanceqqqq_S0_4BaseS1_5IndexS2_8Distancezqqq_S1_5IndexS2_19_DisabledRangeIndexqqqq_S0_4BaseS1_5IndexS2_19_DisabledRangeIndexzqqqq_S1_5IndexS2_8DistanceSs25IntegerLiteralConvertible18IntegerLiteralTypeqqqqq_S0_4BaseS1_5IndexS2_8DistanceS3_18IntegerLiteralType_SsS_9subscriptFqq_S1_5Indexqqqq_S0_4BaseSs12SequenceType9GeneratorSs13GeneratorType7Element) の定義に*Default Implementation* という注釈がある通り、こちらはデフォルト実装の定義であり、
`CollectionType` プロトコルとしての要求はあくまで[`subscript(_: Self.Index) -> Self.Generator.Element`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_CollectionType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intfsub/CollectionType/s:sPSs14CollectionType9subscriptFqq_Ss9Indexable5Indexqqq_S_9GeneratorSs13GeneratorType7Element) です。

`subscript(_: Self.Index) -> Self.Base.Generator.Element` のほうを開くと、

> Constraints
>
> ```
> Self : _CollectionWrapperType, Self.Index == Self.Base.Index
> ```

というのが見えると思いますが、これは「(`CollectionType`である)`Self` が `_CollectionWrapperType` であり、かつ`Self.Index` が `Self.Base.Index` と同じ型であるとき」に、デフォルトの実装が提供されますという意味になります。
つまり、ここでの `Base` は `_CollectionWrapperType` の `Base` であり、 `CollectionType` とは直接の関係はありません。

理解するには `_CollectionWrapperType` を知っておく必要があると思うので、説明します。
`_CollectionWrapperType` はドキュメントには載っていないですが私たちも使用することが可能なプロトコルで、定義は下記の通りです。

```
public protocol _CollectionWrapperType : _SequenceWrapperType {
    typealias Base : CollectionType
    typealias Index : ForwardIndexType = Self.Base.Index
    var _base: Self.Base { get }
}

public protocol _SequenceWrapperType {
    typealias Base : SequenceType
    typealias Generator : GeneratorType = Self.Base.Generator
    var _base: Self.Base { get }
}
```

これを満たすような最小の実装としては:

```
struct FooBarBaz: _CollectionWrapperType {
    let _base = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
}
```

こんな感じです。ここで `Base` は `_base` の型から推測されて`Array<String>`、`Index` は デフォルトで `Array<String>.Index` である `Int`、`Generator` は同様に `IndexingGenerator<Array<String>>` になります。何も省略しないで書くなら:

```
struct FooBarBaz: _CollectionWrapperType {
    typealias Base = Array<String>
    typealias Index = Int
    typealias Generator = IndexingGenerator<Array<String>>
    let _base = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
}
```

このままだと、何のメソッドも持っていない、`_base`プロパティだけを持つただの構造体ですが、これを `CollectionType` に準拠するように宣言します。

```
struct FooBarBaz: _CollectionWrapperType, CollectionType {
    //                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ これを加えただけ
    let _base = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
}
```

この瞬間、先ほどの「(`CollectionType`である)`Self` が `_CollectionWrapperType` であり、かつ`Self.Index` が `Self.Base.Index` と同じ型であるとき」の条件を満たしたことになり、自動的に`subscript(_: Self.Index) -> Self.Base.Generator.Element` を含むいくつかのメソッドのデフォルト実装が提供され、かつそれで`CollectionType`である要件をすべて満たすようになるので、`FooBarBaz` はそのまま`CollectionType`として使用できます。

```
struct FooBarBaz: _CollectionWrapperType, CollectionType {
    let _base = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
}

let fbb = FooBarBaz()
print(fbb[0]) // -> "foo"
print(fbb.count) // -> 3
print(fbb.joinWithSeparator("|")) // -> "foo|bar|baz"
```

というわけで `_CollectionWrapperType` はコレクションをラッピングしつつコレクションのように振る舞う型を作りたいときの便利ツールです。もっとも今のところundocumentedなので、自己責任で使用する必要がありますが・・・

ちなみに、この例では、`Self.Generator == Self.Base.Generator` なので当然 `Self.Genenerator.Element == Self.Base.Generator.Element` となりデフォルト実装が提供された `subscript` がそのまま `CollectionType` のメソッドとして使用できますが、 `Self.Genenerator.Element != Self.Base.Generator.Element` のときはデフォルト実装は提供されますが、`CollectionType`の要件は満たさなくなってしまいますので、その場合は、自前で `subscript(_: Self.Index) -> Self.Generator.Element` などのメソッドを実装する必要があります。